# Only subgroups of Zp (p prime) are 0 and Zp

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

While I find the following theorem very intuitive, I don't really know how to prove it. Could someone help me?

> Prove that the only subgroups of $G := (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z, +)$ with $p$ a prime
>   number are $0$ and $G$ itself. (Hint: Show that for $H < G$ with 
>   $H \neq 0$ we have $1 ∈ H$.)

I'd like to show that any element of $H$, at some point becomes $1$, but how?

Comment: If H is a subgroup of G, then |H| divides |G|. If |G| is a prime number, then what values can |H| have?

Comment: It seems strange that you are at the same attempting a moderately advanced question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437963 and the question here, which is completely elementary, and follows immediately from Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @DerekHolt The problem would be that we didn't hear about Lagrange's theorem yet. And this is indeed one of the simpler of the list of exercises I'm doing. The one you refer to is indeed one of the later, harder ones.

Comment: @Potatocake You don't need to explicitly give an inverse if you can prove it always exists.  Hint: can you prove that the function $x \mapsto ax$ is injective (aka one-to-one) on $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Potatocake The existence (for $a\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$) is all you need, you don't need to construct the inverse. The existence of it follows from [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). See Iulia's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $\exists H\neq 0$ subgroup of $(\mathbb Z_p, +)$.
Let $[a]\in H, [a]\neq [0]\Rightarrow (a,p)=1$. You have the following result:

> > If $a,p\in\mathbb N$, $(a,p)=1$, then there exist $u, v\in \mathbb Z$ such that $au+pv=1$.

Using this, it follows that $\exists u\in\mathbb Z$ such that $au=1$. Going to your result, you get that summing either $[a]$ either $-[a]$ (depends on the sign of $u$) $|u|$ times you get $[1]$, therefore, $[1]\in H$.